# Should I redefine the VMWare virtual NIC's as endpoint devices to bypass Windows Firewall?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, windows-firewall, windows-networking

I have VMWare Workstation 8 on Windows 7. I am an applications developer and I need to start developing and testing an integration between enterprise systems.

I want to run two virtual machines, one Windows Server 2008 R2 and the other Windows 7 and I want a network between those two and the host OS.

I read up a bit on Workstation networking options. I understand there are the default virtual switches, VMnet0 for bridged, VMnet1 for host-only, and VMnet8 for NAT. I want to use bridged. I have added my own virtual switch, VMnet2, and configured that for host-only but I turned off DHCP because the enterprise system I have to install on the Windows Server VM must have a static IP.

I have created my Windows Server VM and assigned it the static IP X.X.X.2. The host OS adapter for VMnet2 has IP X.X.X.1. I had to turn off Windows Firewall on both the host OS and the Windows Server VM in order to be able for each of them to ping the other.

I'm not too excited about the idea of keeping Firewall off on my host OS and I suspect our network admin's prefer it to be on.

I found the following KB that recommends some approaches for dealing with the Windows Firewall:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004813

I either have to try the first approach, "Reconfigure Windows Firewall" or the last, "Redefine the VMware virtual NICs as endpoint devices".

For my scenario, does anyone have any recommendations for which to pursue?